# How can we change the permission of file to 777 of FTP location? using QTP/VB script?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

How can we change the permission of file to 777 of FTP location? using QTP/VB script?

I have file stored in ftp location which is running on Unix server, and I want to change the permission of a file on that location to 777, any help will be welcome

Answer (score 0):

Youre trying to set both read write permission.
You can change file attribute by FileSystemObject.

Get that file & can try below approach.
It will make files readable & writable present Inside a folder. You can modify as per your requirement.

```
Set fso = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
Set folder = fso.GetFolder( folderpath )
Set files = folder.Files

For Each file In files
   file.Attributes = file.Attributes Xor ReadOnly
Next
```